# What does “capped” mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the phrase :

> During months where no time on site is required, time spent on this project **will be capped at 20 hours**.

According to you, the meaning is that "during months with no site activity, one can bill a maximum of 20 hours" or "The word “capped” does not mean that you should bill for 20 hours"?

Comment: this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93400/discussion-on-question-by-fla-what-does-capped-mean-in-this-sentence) because the edits I made have made many comments obsolete. If the author disagrees with the edits, we can roll them back and restore the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence:
 "During months where no time on site is required, time spent on this project will be capped at 20 hours".

in English means:

**During months where no time on site is required, time spent on this project will have a top limit in terms of hours of 20 hours.**

**to cap=to set a maximum limit to something**

You can work off-site when on-site work is not needed, but no more than the maximum limit of 20 hours.

There may be a legal interpretation of this sentence but it is not relevant to understanding what it means in English.

For example, some country or part of a country (state or region) may have special rules regarding working hours, but that does not change what the sentence says in non-legal terms.

Merriam Webster: 
**: an upper limit (as on expenditures) : CEILING
a cap on military spending**

**I can't see whether this is per month or per week.**

Answer (score 1):

**Capped** is an ordinary commercial usage, meaning "upper permissible limit".

You'll read

- **Expenses are capped at £20 per day**
- **Costs are capped at £20,000 for the project**
- **Project time is capped at 10 hours**

Under these conditions, if I spent £30 on any given day, I can still only ask my company for £20.

It's a general way of specifying a limit.  Without the exact context, it's impossible to know whether "Project time is capped at 10 hours" means "It's only permitted to *work* 10 hours" or if it means "It's only permitted to ask for 10 hours' *money*".